# Switching from GPS_Provider & Network _Provider in android

Tags: android, networking, gps, geocoding

I'm working on GPS based application that gets the address based on GPS provider but sometimes it doesn't work due to lack of signal like as at underground parking or similar places. So in such situtation i want to take the address through Network provider and send SMS via sendSMS() method. It has to repeat every 10 mints and call the sendSMS() method with updated Location.

The code for getting GPS location is below could you please suggest me to edit it according to my need?

```
    public class WPGActivity extends Activity  {
        ImageButton start;
        Button login;

        String ADDRESS, LOCATION;

        TextView addressText, locationText;
        Location currentLocation;
        double currentLatitude;
        double currentLongitude;

        @Override
        public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.main);

            start=(ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.imageButton1);
            login=(Button)findViewById(R.id.button1);

            addressText = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.addressText);
            locationText = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.locationText);

            myLocation();



          //  if(ACTIVE_MODE==1) startApp();

            start.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {           
                public void onClick(View v) { 



                getAddress(); // to get address
                sendSMS(); // to send sms
                sendEmail(); // to send email

                }
            });



        }


        public void myLocation(){

            LocationManager locationManager = 
                (LocationManager)this.getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);

            LocationListener locationListener = new LocationListener() {
                public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
                    updateLocation(location);
                }
                public void onStatusChanged(
                        String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {}
                public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {}
                public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {}
            };

            locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 1000*60*5, 30, locationListener);

        }
          public void getAddress(){
                try{
                    Geocoder gcd = new Geocoder(this, Locale.getDefault());
                    List<Address> addresses = 
                        gcd.getFromLocation(currentLatitude, currentLongitude,100);
                    if (addresses.size() > 0) {
                        StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder();
                        for(int i = 0; i < addresses.size(); i++){
                            Address address =  addresses.get(i);
                            int maxIndex = address.getMaxAddressLineIndex();
                            for (int x = 0; x <= maxIndex; x++ ){
                                result.append(address.getAddressLine(x));
                                result.append(",");
                            }               
                            result.append(address.getLocality());
                            result.append(",");
                            result.append(address.getPostalCode());
                            result.append("\n\n");
                        }
                        ADDRESS = result.toString();
                        addressText.setText(ADDRESS);
                    }
                }
                catch(IOException ex){
                    ADDRESS= ex.getMessage().toString();
                    addressText.setText(ADDRESS);
                }
            }

            void updateLocation(Location location){
                currentLocation = location;
                currentLatitude = currentLocation.getLatitude();
                currentLongitude = currentLocation.getLongitude();
                locationText.setText(LOCATION);
            }

    }
```